# Extract values in R

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataset as below:

```
| group | begin | end | 
| ----- | ----- | --- | 
| 001   | 1     | 1   | 
| 001   | 1     | 2   | 
| 001   | 2     | 6   |
| 001   | 2     | 7   |
```

For example, the `begin` value in the second row is 1, which matches the `end` value in the first row, so I extract the values from the first row for the second row.

The resulting dataset will look like this:

```
| group | begin | end |  
|    -1 |   1   | 1   |
| 001   | 1     | 2   |
| 001   | 2     | 6   |
| 001   | 2     | 7   |
```

I tried `which()` and `match()` but it has beyond my R programming knowledge and I'm wondering how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can `match` `begin` and `end` columns to get row number to extract values from `x` and `y` columns.

```
df[c("base_x", "base_y")] <- df[match(df$begin, df$end), c("x", "y")]

df
#  group begin end  x  y base_x base_y
#1   001    NA   1  0  0     NA     NA
#2   001     1   2 15 18      0      0
#3   001     2   6 23 56     15     18
#4   001     2   7 11 19     15     18
#5   001     6  10 20 23     23     56
#6   001    10  11 18 19     20     23
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "001"
), begin = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 6, 10), end = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 
11L), x = c(0L, 15L, 23L, 11L, 20L, 18L), y = c(0L, 18L, 56L, 
19L, 23L, 19L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```